# Getting Error on opening simul8 file

Tags: c++

I want to open simul8 file using c++ I have done the following

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#import "C:\Program Files\SIMUL8\S8.exe" named_guids
using namespace SIMUL8;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

IS8Simulation* MYSIMUL8 = NULL;
IUnknown* pUnk = NULL;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(SIMUL8::CLSID_S8Simulation,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,__uuidof(IUnknown),(void**)&pUnk);
_bstr_t bstrFileName = ::SysAllocString(L"D:\\Demo1.s8");

hr = MYSIMUL8->Open(bstrFileName); 
MYSIMUL8->RunSim(2400);
}
```

I get the error message Unhandled exception at 0x004017e7 in SimTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. in s8.tli

```
inline HRESULT IS8Simulation::Open ( _bstr_t FileName ) {
    HRESULT _hr = raw_Open(FileName); ON THIS LINE
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;
}
```

kindly help me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.. The error was that I am not Initializing the COM object I have modified the code as follows...

```
// SimTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#import "C:\Program Files\SIMUL8\S8.exe" named_guids
using namespace SIMUL8;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//Simul8.Simulation8 *pObject;
IS8Simulation * MYSIMUL8;
MYSIMUL8=(struct IS8Simulation *) malloc(sizeof(struct IS8Simulation ));


IUnknown * pUnk ;

CoInitialize( NULL );
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(SIMUL8::CLSID_S8Simulation ,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,__uuidof(IUnknown),(void**)&pUnk);


hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IS8Simulation), (void**)&MYSIMUL8);

_bstr_t bstrFileName = ::SysAllocString(L"D:\\Demo1.s8");


MYSIMUL8->Open(bstrFileName);
MYSIMUL8->Visible = true;
MYSIMUL8->RunSim(2400);



// Uninitialize COM.
//CoUninitialize();
}
```

Now my Simul8 Demo is running :-)